# Best way to store a variadic list of arguments to be executed in the future?

Tags: c++

(Title edited to clarify intent.
Original Title: "Can I heap-allocate a va_list to use it later?")

I'm trying to develop a scripting system for my game that allows me to look at all functions which will be called on a future frame and what arguments they will take. Since the args these functions take aren't all the same, I figured the best approach would be to make a struct containing an unwrapper function that takes a va_list, and a va_list to be passed to it.  Each unwrapper function just takes the va_list, separates it back into multiple variables, and passes it to a corresponding real function. Then each script has a queue of those structs to be executed on a given frame.

Here's the script class:

```
class MoveScript {
public:
    MoveScript();
    MoveScript(std::string name, std::function<void()> move_script);

    void activate(); //Clear the ScriptFrame queue, then call move_script()
    void execute(float frame); //Checks if the front ScriptFrame is set to this frame. If it is, then call its execute function and remove it from the queue

    std::string name;
    std::queue<ScriptFrame> frames;
private:
    std::function<void()> move_script{ []() {} }; //Runs whenever a new script is activated, populates the ScriptFrame queue
};
```

Here's the ScriptFrame class:

```
class ScriptFrame {
public:
    ScriptFrame();
    ScriptFrame(float frame);

    void execute(); //Executes each function_call in the queue with its corresponding function_arg

    float frame;

    std::queue<std::function<void(ScriptArg)>> function_calls;
    std::queue<ScriptArg> function_args;
};
```

Here's a ScriptArg:

```
struct ScriptArg {
    ScriptArg();
    ScriptArg(int num_args, std::va_list va);
    void destroy(); //Call va_end() so I don't have to do it within the unwrapper funcs
    int num_args;
    std::va_list va;
};
```

And here's an example of all of this in practice

```
    script("wait", [this]() {
        execute_frame(0, [this]() {
            push_function(&BattleObject::SET_RATE, 1, 0.5);
        });
    });

void BattleObject::SET_RATE(ScriptArg args) {
    UNWRAP(rate, float);
    set_rate(rate);
}
```

Where `script` initializes a MoveScript and adds it to a table, `execute_frame` creates a new ScriptFrame to execute on the given frame, `push_function` pushes the unwrapper function and a va_list generated by the args to the ScriptFrame's respective queues, and `UNWRAP` is a macro that expands to `float rate = va_arg(args.va, float);`

As I’m sure you can already tell, this code doesn’t work because of how a va_list becomes invalid after the function which called `va_start` returns. I found another question about it but couldn’t find any suggestions that I figured could work. I’ve seen stuff about storing a void* instead of va_list and getting the args directly within `push_function`, but since the args passed can be of different types, I don’t think there’s any way for me to safely use `va_arg` at that point. So I was wondering, if I heap-allocate the va_list, will that allow me to store it properly, or does it become invalidated as soon as the function which takes the ellipsis goes out of scope? If it does, can I possibly store the ellipsis directly instead of a va_list, then create a va_list in the unwrapper function? Or just generally if there’s a better way to accomplish my goal, what would that be? Let me know if there’s any other info I should provide.

Thanks!

Comment: I did not really understand what you are trying to do. But `va_list` is almost certainly not the answer. Basically its only decent use case is to interface with C APIs. If you need functions that can be called with an unspecified number of arguments, then use variadic function templates instead.

Comment: I'm out of votes but second @user17732522's suggestion. Don't go C on your C++.

Comment: If your goal is just to store function arguments to call the stored functions with later, you don't need any of this. You can just pass the arguments as captures of or directly in a lambda which is then stored in `std::function<void()>`, e.g. something like `push_function([]{ BattleObject::SET_RATE(1, 0.5); })`.

Comment: @Ted Here, have one of mine :) (he he)

Comment: @PaulSanders Paying it forward I see :-D

Comment: Problem with handling it directly as a lambda is I need to be able to directly check which functions will get called and which args they’ll take (I.E. “I’m simulating how many frames it’ll take to reach a target frame using a simulated rate, and if set_rate will be called at any point in the script, I need to also adjust my simulated rate”), and a lambda doesn’t help me figure out what the args will be without calling it. I’ll check out using a variadic template though, worst case scenario I still use a va_list to unwrap but I pass the variadic type around since it should stay valid.

Comment: `va_list` is type-unsafe, error-prone C. The proper, type-safe, natural C++ way to do this is have a `std::tuple` represent captured function parameters. I didn't follow the question, I could not understand everything with a brief read-through, but the capsule summary is to capture function parameters in a `std::tuple`, which also captures their type, and they can be pulled out later to make a function call, and C++ will do all the heavily-lifting to make sure that the function call type's parameters match. I've done exactly this before. But this didn't look like anything like the question.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I tried tuples to store the data as a few answers suggested, but that didn't work because I needed to be able to properly index them while the function was still being wrapped, at which point the number and types of args were still unknown. Due to how templates work, I couldn't find a way to store the entire tuple in the ScriptArg struct either *(Note: It's entirely possible that all of this was possible to work around and I just couldn't figure it out, but either way I found a way to handle it without using tuples which works for my purposes).*

In any case, I managed to accomplish what I was looking for using a queue of std::any instead of a va_list, and populating the queue with all of the variadic arguments the function took. Handling the variadic args using a tuple still didn't seem to work, but as it turns out, I could just use a vector instead. Here's what the full process looks like.

ScriptArg declaration:

```
struct ScriptArg {
    ScriptArg();
    ScriptArg(int num_args, std::queue<std::any> args);

    std::any get_arg(); //Get the argument at the front of the queue, pop it and return the argument
    void pop();

    int num_args;
    std::queue<std::any> args;
};
```

The UNWRAP macros:

```
//Declares a variable of the given type and extracts its value from the queue
#define UNWRAP(var_name, type) type var_name = std::any_cast<type>(args.get_arg());
//Same as the above, but for variables that were already declared
#define UNWRAP_NO_DECL(var_name, type) var_name = std::any_cast<type>(args.get_arg());
```

Wrapping a member function:

```
template<typename ...T>
void push_function(void (BattleObject::* function)(ScriptArg), T... args) {
    std::queue<std::any> queue = extract_variadic_to_queue(args...);
    ScriptArg sa(sizeof...(args), queue);
    active_script_frame.function_calls.push(std::bind(function, this, std::placeholders::_1)); //I believe I could also just bind the arguments directly instead of putting a placeholder here, but since I need to store the arguments separately for other reasons, this is fine.
    active_script_frame.function_args.push(sa);
}

template<typename ...T>
std::queue<std::any> extract_variadic_to_queue_impl(const T&... args) {
    std::vector<std::any> vec = { args... };
    std::queue<std::any> ret;
    for (int i = 0, max = vec.size(); i < max; i++) {
        ret.push(vec[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}

template<typename ...T>
std::queue<std::any> extract_variadic_to_queue(T... args) {
    return extract_variadic_to_queue_impl(std::any(args)...);
}
```

And besides the fact that I need to unwrap the float as a double due to std::any's type promotion, the unwrapping function itself looks exactly the same:

```
void BattleObject::SET_RATE(ScriptArg args) {
    UNWRAP(rate, double);
    set_rate(rate);
}
```

I'm still not sure if there's a more efficient way to handle this, but it's overall the simplest method I could find for storing future function arguments without needing to know their quantities and type until they were actually called, which was my end goal. Sorry for not making that more clear in the initial question, but I appreciate you all steering me in the right direction and away from va_lists. Thanks!